# sp_send_dbmail error

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005

How can i pass multiple query in a `@query parameter` in `sp_send_dbmail`?

For example:

```
select count(*) from TableA
IF count(*)/ @@rowcount = 0  
Exec sp_send_dbmail @profile_name = xx, @recipients = 'xx@abc.com',@subject = 'Test', @body= ' No rows';
IF count(*)/ @@rowcount > 0
Exec sp_send_dbmail @profile_name = xx, @recipients = 'xx@abc.com',@subject = 'Test', 
@body= ' xx rows';
```

I am not getting any error message, but it stops after the first select statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do the `select count(*) from TableA` you do not keep the value somewhere, it only execute and return the result from your query. This why the `if` statements are not firing. You could do something like this:

```
DECLARE @c AS int
SET @c = (select count(*) from TableA)

IF @c = 0
Exec sp_send_dbmail @profile_name = xx, @recipients = 'xx@abc.com',@subject = 'Test', @body= 'No rows';

IF @c > 0
Exec sp_send_dbmail @profile_name = xx, @recipients = 'xx@abc.com',@subject = 'Test', 
@body= ' xx rows';
```

Though I have some reservations about putting this kind of logic on the SQL side. But since I don't know how you are using this, it should work for now.